# Reading records from Excel and saving it to SQL server 2014

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, excel

I have few columns in my excel sheet -> Job, Hours, Notes
There is a table in my database 'Tasks', where I have columns -> Task, Hours, Comment.

I have to read data from Excel file through ASP.Net page and import all data to SQL server database.
I have added FileUpload for excel file browsing and a button event to read the data.

I have seen this code:

```
protected void btnUpload_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (FileUpload1.HasFile)
    {
        string FileName = Path.GetFileName(FileUpload1.PostedFile.FileName);
        string Extension = Path.GetExtension(FileUpload1.PostedFile.FileName);
        string FolderPath = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["FolderPath"];

        string FilePath = Server.MapPath(FolderPath + FileName);
        FileUpload1.SaveAs(FilePath);
        Import_To_Grid(FilePath, Extension, rbHDR.SelectedItem.Text);
    }
}

private void Import_To_Grid(string FilePath, string Extension, string isHDR)
{
    string conStr = "";
    switch (Extension)
    {
        case ".xls": //Excel 97-03
            conStr = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Excel03ConString"].ConnectionString;
            break;
        case ".xlsx": //Excel 07
            conStr = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Excel07ConString"].ConnectionString;
            break;
    }
    conStr = String.Format(conStr, FilePath, isHDR);
    OleDbConnection connExcel = new OleDbConnection(conStr);
    OleDbCommand cmdExcel = new OleDbCommand();
    OleDbDataAdapter oda = new OleDbDataAdapter();
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    cmdExcel.Connection = connExcel;

    //Get the name of First Sheet
    connExcel.Open();
    DataTable dtExcelSchema;
    dtExcelSchema = connExcel.GetOleDbSchemaTable(OleDbSchemaGuid.Tables, null);
    string SheetName = dtExcelSchema.Rows[0]["TABLE_NAME"].ToString();
    connExcel.Close();

    //Read Data from First Sheet
    connExcel.Open();
    cmdExcel.CommandText = "SELECT * From [" + SheetName + "]";
    oda.SelectCommand = cmdExcel;
    oda.Fill(dt);
    connExcel.Close();

    //Bind Data to GridView
    GridView1.Caption = Path.GetFileName(FilePath);
    GridView1.DataSource = dt;
    GridView1.DataBind();
}
```

But this binds with the GridView and I want to update my database. Any recommendations how that can be achieved?

Answer (score 1):

Not clear. but if it is what I think it is then : 
Before

```
//Bind Data to GridView
    GridView1.Caption = Path.GetFileName(FilePath);
    GridView1.DataSource = dt;
    GridView1.DataBind();
```

You can have an update function called which will update the database. There is not update or interaction with database here.